Selenium Firefox - Profile not loading
.\geckodriver --version = geckodriver 0.35.0 (9f0a0036bea4 2024-08-03 07:11 +0000)

    Name: selenium
    Version: 4.27.1
    Summary: Official Python bindings for Selenium WebDriver
    Home-page: https://www.selenium.dev
    Author:
    Author-email:
    License: Apache 2.0
    Location: C:\Users\Whatisit\PycharmProjects\api_database\.venv\Lib\site-packages
    Requires: cert


Tried multiple ways of using options:
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = webdriver.Options()
options = Options()from selenium.webdriver.firefox import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = webdriver.Options()
options = Options()


profile_path = hard coded or dynamic profile paths)
Version 1:
options.set_profile(profile_path)

Version 2:
options.add_argument("-profile")
options.add_argument(profile_path)

Version 3:
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)


In combination of adding:
options.binary_location = to gecko


Attempted another way:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import service

service_args=[]
service_args.append("--profile")
service_args.append("/path/to/profile")
service = service.Service(service_args=service_args)
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import service


Adding gecko direct to Service, and or FirefoxService


I have tried running various tests such as:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/blob/trunk//examples/python/tests/browsers/test_firefox.py#L157-L165
The profile one passes yet, my profile is not loaded.
I have output the Service log and there is no issues. There was one error:
services.settings: ignoring preference override of remote settings server
How do I fix this?

Could you please post your code? Also, do you think the solution to your problem will somehow depend on the number of days you tried to find it? If not then the information of how many days you worked on the problem seems superfluous and adds no additional information to the question.

Also note that if you "have done everything possible" then we cannot help you. Any suggestion we might give you will, by definition, have already been tried by you. Are you sure you have done everything possible? It looks like such task would require a lot more than 3 days.
